# Calculating Aggregate of Aggregate in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

I have a Dataset that lists the Stock and Target for each Product at each Branch.

```
+--------------+---------+--------+-------+--------+
| ProductGroup | Product | Branch | Stock | Target |
+--------------+---------+--------+-------+--------+
| A            | A1      |    100 |    12 |     20 |
| A            | A1      |    101 |    24 |     30 |
| A            | A1      |    102 |     9 |     10 |
| A            | A2      |    100 |    17 |     60 |
| A            | A2      |    101 |    12 |     30 |
| A            | A2      |    102 |    16 |     88 |
| B            | B1      |    100 |    42 |    150 |
| B            | B2      |    101 |    65 |    142 |
| B            | B3      |    102 |    98 |    700 |
+--------------+---------+--------+-------+--------+
```

I'm trying to create a Report that is grouped by ProductGroup which shows a **Count of Products, for that Product Group, where the Sum of the Stock at all Branches/Sum of Target at all Branches < 0.2**

Note: I want the Summary to display Stock by Branch also, so Grouping the Data in the Query is not an option.

Is there any way to do this!!

Many thanks in advance to any help received.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Row Grouping on your tablix. The images I'm posting are from Report Builder 3.0, but it's very similar to 2.0. Here's an article from Microsoft on how to group rows in 2.0: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220419(v=sql.100).aspx

Here are instructions for how I do it in 3.0, which is very similar. Assuming you've already created a tablix to do this, right click on the row you want to group (not the headers). Go to row group, group properties. 
[image: GroupProperties]

Click Add and chose a field to group on. In this case, you'd want to add ProductGroup and then Product.
[image: AddGroup]

Then right click your other textboxes and select expression. Choose the aggregate function you need for that field. Make sure that it appears as SUM(Fields!Qty.Value) and not SUM(Fields!Qty.Value, "dataset1"). The latter will give you the SUM for your dataset and not your group.
[image]